# Fill items into ListView from top?

Tags: android, listview

Somehow `ListView` is filled from bottom. Do you know why?

There are three items in the list, but the content need to fill from top.

`ListView` is filled with `CursorAdapter`, like:

```
adapter=new ItemCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), resultSet, 0);
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[image]

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="{relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:width="100dp"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

mylist.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Pls, provide your xml code.

Comment: Post your *XML* code which contains `List View`.

Comment: @János Yes your `Layout` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` form your `ListView` code.

> This property will force your `ListView` to bottom.
>
> Just use as Below.

```
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp">
    </ListView>
```

> If you want below `EditText` then use `layout below` property.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/edittext"
    android:layout_marginTop="66dp">
</ListView>
```

Comment: I want to keep `ListView` under the `TextEdit` control. Are you sure I need to remove `layout_alignParentBottom`?